# Add string value in Xpath drive.Findelement

Tags: c#, string

Hi i just would add string "value" in path

my code looke like :

```
 string value = "Dodaj ofertę";
 drive.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@value='Dodaj ofertę']")).Click();
```

All i need to do is just

```
drive.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@value='{value}']")).Click();
```

but this is incorrect. How can i do that?
Please be patient for newbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the string interpolation feature you should add `$` before the string:

```
drive.FindElement(By.XPath($"//*[@value='{value}']")).Click();
```

And if prior to C# 6.0 using `string.Format`:

```
drive.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//*[@value='{0}']", value))).Click();
```